# Dealloc objects of another class

Tags: iphone, memory-management, dealloc

Hi I generally create objects of another classes. can you please tel me if this wil be in the auto release pool? or should we release it manually.

Comment: You need to show some code or explain your question better, or both.  Some objects you create might be autoreleased, others might not...

Answer (score 1):

if you init copy or new them you'll have to deallocate them if you put an autorlease with the allocation then they will be autoreleased

for example

```
Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init]; //you'll have release it somewhere yourself
```

And

```
Foo *foo = [[[Foo alloc] init] autorelease];// this will be autreleased
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple case is : if you use init, you are responsible for releasing it, either by calling release or by calling autorelease.

e.g.

```
NSString *myString = [NSString alloc] init]; // You need to release this
...
[myString release]; // Now it's released - don't use it again!
```

or if you are going give it to someone else

```
NSString *myString = [NSString alloc] init]; // This needs releasing
...
return [myString autorelease]; // You are finished with it but someone else might want it
```

However, there's a few other cases.

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hi"];
```

This object is in the autorelease pool already - don't release it!

```
NSString *secondString = [myString copy];
```

This object needs releasing - it is *not* autoreleased.

**Rule of thumb** : Anything with init, copy or new in the name - you made it, you release it. Anything else will be autoreleased.

Comment: The Rule of thumb is not quite correct: it's not the `init` but the `alloc` that demands a release, additionally it's missing `new`.

Comment: Blast, I always forget `new` :( I've edited my answer, thanks!